# TwoWayView Android Lib Carousel Effect In Scroll With Smooth Animate

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, android-animation

I need to make a `ListView` using the Lib `TwoWayView` have the same behavior that occurs in **Sappos App**, where after 
applying scroll the `List`, an animation centers the item with the highest percentage visible.

**Edited**

For the example below I costumizei an example on github: [Vertical Horizontal ListView having a ListView](https://github.com/lalit3686/VerticalHorizontalListView)

[image: Example]

If anyone has suggestion, have already done something, appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the support is functionality was added

https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view/issues/53

> I've just fixed an issue in the scrollBy(int) method that was apply
>   the delta in the wrong direction (see 2fd1ea7). It should be working
>   fine now. I've have also landed
>   smoothScrollBy/smoothScrollToPosition() support in #20.